# How to Increase/Update Variable Group value using Azure Devops Build Definition?

Tags: tags, azure-devops

Am working on Azure Devops CI&CD. Here, my release name must be in Version number using tags. Am getting this with the help of Variable Groups, by adding tags and value to it. Here am getting the tags value as constant like a static for every release like 1.1,1.2,1.3 etc.

Now am trying to increase/update my tag value dynamically for every new release triggered after completion of my Build Definition successfully which looks like 1.1,1.2,2.1,2.2,3.1,3.2 etc.It is possible with the help of statically by variable group, but manually we need to update it.

Is it possible to Increase/Update the tags value in Variable Group with the Build Definition tasks or other process.If possible, please suggest me to "How to done this?"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can overwrite/update the value of the variables by using the [logging command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to set the variables again in Azure Devops Build pipleline:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"
```

To increase the value dynamically, you need to use the token [`$(Rev:.r)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/pipelines/build/options?view=vsts&tabs=yaml#tokens). You can custom the variables based on the `$(Build.BuildNumber)` or `$(Release.ReleaseName)`as they will increase the value dynamically...

Just reference this thread to custom the variables:https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/666#issuecomment-386769445

---

**UPDATE:**

If you just want to update the value of the variables which defined in a specific Variable Group, then you can call REST API in build pipeline to achieve that:

```
PUT https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{ProjectName or ID}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{Variable Group ID}?api-version=5.0-preview.1

Content-Type: application/json

Request Body:

{"id":2,"type":"Vsts","name":"VG0926","variables":{"TEST0926":{"isSecret":false,"value":"0930"}}}
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE2:**

You can write a PowerShell script to call the REST API, then add a PowerShell task to run the script in your build pipeline: ([Use the OAuth token to access the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=vsts#use-the-oauth-token-to-access-the-rest-api))

Below sample for your reference:

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{Variable Group ID}?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
Write-Host $url

function CreateJsonBody
{

    $value = @"

{"id":2,"type":"Vsts","name":"VG0926","variables":{"TEST0926":{"isSecret":false,"value":"0930"}}}

"@

 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody


$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}

Write-Host "New Variable Value:" $pipeline.variables.TEST0926.value
```

---

**UPDATE3:**

Well, tested again, below scripts works for me as well. You can try it, just replace the parameters accordingly:

```
# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "","PAT here")))
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/Test0924/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/1?api-version=5.0-preview.1"

$json = '{"id":1,"type":"Vsts","name":"VG0928","variables":{"TEST0928":{"isSecret":false,"value":"0931"}}}'
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
Write-Host "New Variable Value:" $pipeline.variables.TEST0928.value
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Andy. Here, I want to update variable value of Group Variable which is in Library of VSTS with the help of Build task. Not to update the variable of build of the same build.

Comment: Thank You. Is there any task for calling RestAPI in Build Definition

Comment: I tried for it. But, it isn't done for me. Can you give some more details regarding to it

Comment: @Mani You can write a PowerShell script to call the REST API, then add a Powershell task to run the script in your build pipeline. See the updated answer.

Comment: Ya I tried it, but result is same and the commands which I used is:

    `$Url = "https://dev.azure.com/xxxxx/AKSARMTemplates/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/2?api-version=4.1-preview.1"                                                                 
$Body = @{ 
    id=2
    type = "Vsts"
    name = "versiongroup"
    variables= { version =
     { isSecret = "false", value = "0930" }}
}


$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Put' -Uri $Url -Body $Body

Write-Host $Result`

Comment: @Mani The format is incorrect for the request body, please exactly follow the sample I provided in above answer. Besides, please confirm the `Variable Group ID` is correct on your side. You can call REST API `GET https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{ProjectName}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups` to get the  `Variable Group ID`.

Comment: Thank you..Its worked for me(Update three is worked)

Answer (score 10):

You can simply update any number of variables in an Azure Devops variable group using its built-in `az pipelines variable-group variable update` command. You can use this command in a `script` task in the pipeline definition as shown below.

ps: Replace all the upper case values with corresponding values except the `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN`.

```
variables:
- group: VARIABLE_GROUP_NAME

jobs:
- job: UpdateVarGroup
  steps:
  - script: |
      newValue="This is the updated value"

      echo $SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN | az devops login
      az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id $(group_id) \
        --name NAME_OF_THE_VARIABLE \
        --value "${newValue}" \
        --org https://dev.azure.com/YOUR_ORGANIZATION_NAME \
        --project AZURE_DEVOPS_PROJECT
    displayName: 'Update variable inside a variable group'
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

In order for this example to work, you need to have a variable inside your variable group called `group_id`. The value of that needs to be set to the group id of the variable group, which can be obtained by simply looking at the url of your variable group. (The group id is the value for `variableGroupId` in the url of your browser when you are inside the variable group)

System.AccessToken is required for `az devops login`

Comment: You need also to grant administrator role for "Project Collection Build Service" in security roles of the variable group: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53001159

Answer (score 3):

If you want to update a variable group's value, use the REST.API methods.
Rather than constructing the PUT request body manually, use a GET first to get the original JSON, update only what you need, then replay it as a PUT. I used to keep the variable group id also as a variable in that group to avoid hard-coding.

```
variables:
  - group: MyVarGroup

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/$(VariableGroupId)?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
      $header = @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"
      }
      $def = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $header

      $def.variables.MyTestVar.value = "NewValue"
      $body = @($def) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 -Compress
      $def = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Put' -Uri $url -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $header -Body $body
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this task to update the value of my variables inside my group.

[Shared variable updater (preview)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Lanalua.lanalua-variableupdater)

Dont forget to set those settings :

1. Requires 'Allow scripts to access the OAuth token' in agent job additional options
2. Set administrator role to 'Project Collection Build Service' in the variable group.

**In case of using a YAML pipeline**

When using a YAML pipeline, the OAuth token is automatically added (no need for step 1 above), but requires a bit of work to make accessible for the powershell script. Use [the guidance here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#access-to-oauth-token) to be able to use the token.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite variables using the REST API with a PowerShell task without needing to create a PAT.

1. You'll need to first going into the agent job and set "Allow scripts to access OAuth token".
2. You'll need too go to your variable group and add the 'Project Collection Build Service' as an administrator.
3. Now you can call the Rest API using the OAuth Bearer token. Code for reference:

```
$id = <variable group id>

# This is using some environment variables provided by the pipeline to build the URL
$url = ("$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{0}?api-version=5.0-preview" -f $id)

# You might find it useful to us a GET method to grab the variable group, update it and then convert it to this json string rather than doing this here
$json = '{"id":$id,"type":"Vsts","name":"<Variable Group Name>","<Variable Name":{"ThisIsMyVariable":{"isSecret":false,"value":"20"}}}'

$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this task to manage variable groups from Pipelines:
[ManageVariableGroupTask](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MorenoBruschi.manage-variable-group-task&ssr=false#overview)

Using this you can Create/Update/Delete variable groups and do the same operations on variables contained in them.

Hope that's helpfull!