# Azure Devops : Updating Variable in VariableGroup

Tags: azure, azure-devops

My Question is related to Azure Devops build/release pipeline. I have created a variable group with IP address & port of kafka broker which will be used by applications.

Now, as part of the automation, we are creating kafka broker on the fly, which is also one of the pipeline task. So, as soon as infra pipeline is done, we would like to update the variables in variable group so that applications can use them for deployment.

I am looking for a programatic way to update the variable in azure variable groups.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399076/how-to-increase-update-variable-group-value-using-azure-devops-build-definition

Comment: The above link solved my problem