# How to pass secret variable from one stage to another AzureDevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using classic Azure DevOps release pipeline and there are 3 different stages.

In first stage I am running a PowerShell script and that sets up a dynamic variable as `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=svc_password;issecret=true;isOutput=true]$token"`

In second stage I am running a python script and need to access above variable value, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Is this what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485621/share-variables-across-stages-in-azure-devops-pipelines

Comment: @AmanB Yes but I am using classic pipeline not yaml so how to pass this value as argument in python script next stage .

Comment: Answer is already provided on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62128394/pass-azure-devops-release-pipelineclassic-editor-output-variable-to-multiple-j . You must use YAML to consume output variables in different jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the documentation: [Set an output variable in a future job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-an-output-variable-in-a-future-job).

Example:

```
jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
  - bash: |
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVar;isoutput=true;issecret=true]this is from job A"
    name: passOutput
- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['passOutput.myOutputVar'] ]  
  steps:
  - bash: |
     echo $(myVarFromJobA)
```